# Is there any free tool to explain the interactions between website pages and elements on a big single screen?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, web-app, wireframe

Is there any tool to explain the interactions between website pages and elements on a big single screen?

I have all screenshot images for all pages of websites, Some are lightbox on same page. some are forms.

I want to show relation between all pages on one screen. By where clicking will come which page , which lightbox , etc.

I have final screenshot (JPG Images) of all 20 pages and stages of condition of pages. Images sizes are 1024x768. I don't want to make slideshow. I want to show all pages in one screen and to explain changes by adding comments with pointing arrows.

I'm looking for **Free** online/Offline tool.

Comment: This seems quite a reach.

Answer (score 2):

I am developing [WireframeSketcher rapid wireframing tool](http://wireframesketcher.com). It has the ability to create screen flows. You can get the result that looks like this:

[image: WireframeSketcher Screenflow]

You can also use existing images to create screens. Create your screens, then link them together, put them in a storyboard and you get the screen flow automatically.

Comment: Very nice . The screen shot you added I exactly want like this but except wireframe I want to use real images files. Is this tool not free?

Comment: The tool is not free. You can use real images too. Create a screens using Image widget, link them using Hotspots.

Answer (score 0):

[Cacoo.com](https://cacoo.com/)  is a free diagram creating site you can use. Features are limited for the free plan but paid plans allow you to collaborate and create additional diagrams, depending on your use the free version may suffice.

You can make wireframes like the below (to any level of details you like) and link buttons to other pages using arrows to create a storyboard.
[image]

In your case you can zoom out from your wireframe and connect pages like the storyboard below, connecting elements like forms and links to arbitrary items.
[image]

Comment: I have already seen it but I want to show all at one screen. Some thing like flow chart

Comment: @JitendraVyas Cacoo can scale quite large, so you can create a storyboard of quite detailed screens as necessary, I've uploaded a better example

Comment: In you example you are using wireframe made inside Cacoo and I'm taking about to use real final design files in JPG format. I tried to uploaded my 26 files on Cacoo but it got hanged.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://speckyboy.com/2011/02/23/10-completely-free-wireframing-and-mockup-tools/) that has 10 different offerings and they are all free!